# proper way to replace view form

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I need to override `account.account_aged_balance_view` in order to hide a field (`Period Length (days)`) as well add new field in the same time.

I tried the following in my custom module view:

```xml
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record id="account_aged_balance_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Aged Partner Balance</field>
        <field name="model">account.aged.trial.balance</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.account_aged_balance_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Report Options">
                <separator string="Aged Partner Balance"/>
                <label string="Dariel Partner Balance is a more detailed report of your receivables by intervals. When opening that report, Odoo asks for the name of the company, the Start Date and the size of the interval to be analyzed (in days). Odoo then calculates a table of credit balance by start Date. So if you request an interval of 30 days Odoo generates an analysis of creditors for the past month, past two months, and so on. "/>
                <group col="4">
                    <field name="date_from"/>
                    <newline/>
                    <field name="result_selection" widget="radio"/>
                    <field name="target_move" widget="radio"/>
                </group>
                <field name="journal_ids" required="0" invisible="1"/>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

those `XML` appended to the modal form instead of replacing the original form, like shown in the image.
[image]

so, am I doing it right (ofcourse it's not right) or how the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can both replace the whole form view or remove and add only the fields you want. You have to use the *xpath* to do that.

To replace the whole view:

```
<record id="account_aged_balance_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Aged Partner Balance</field>
    <field name="model">account.aged.trial.balance</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.account_aged_balance_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr='//form' position='replace'>

            < your form view >

        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Or you can remove only what you don't want and add what you want with:

```
<record id="account_aged_balance_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Aged Partner Balance</field>
    <field name="model">account.aged.trial.balance</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.account_aged_balance_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

        <xpath expr='//field[@name="period_length"]' position='replace'/>

        <xpath expr='//field[@name=" < name of the field you want to put yours after > "]' position='after'>
            <field name=' < your field name > '/>
        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>
```

I did not try it, but it should work.